# Differences between navigator location and google maps

Tags: cordova, location, maps, navigator

I have an application in phonegap with a geolocation, but I'm wondering if someone can tell me about this behavior. Sometimes my application can't find location sometimes it does. 
And when it doesn't I try google maps, and it works fine there. So my question is what is a difference between navigator and what google maps uses? And how can my application get location when Google maps has it.

Comment: which version of geolocation plugin do you use?

Comment: I'm using phonegap 3.4.0 and geolocation plugin 0.3.6

Comment: any information on this topic?

Comment: nope, seems to be a random bug. i would totaly rebuild my project, create a new one and copy the index and css /images into the new folder so you can exlude any problems with your project.